# Pass two arguments to translation hook of 18next

Tags: javascript, i18next

Is there a way to pass two arguments to the `const {t} = useTranslation();` of i18next?

```
// translation_en.js
    foo: {
        cat: 'Cat'
        dog: 'Dog'
    }
```

Usage

```
t('cat', 'dog')
```

Currently, this only returns

> Cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just join outputs of `t` with single arg?

```
 console.log([
    t('cat'),
    t('dog')
  ].join(' '));
```

Comment: That is how I am doing it right now, but I thought i18next might offer something internal

Comment: OK then, I might be wrong, but i think it accepts only 1 argument, so it's impossible without some hacky way.